# Android: Auto-Cancel an alarm after a certain period or flag

Tags: android, android-alarms

Since i haven't seen any threads regarding canceling an alarm without using any button, or invoking in onClick. I decided to ask this question as well as i would like to also include the question, (since its somewhat related to each other), regarding assigning or invoking alarms simultaneously with different trigger time, because I've read that if you set another alarm, it will just stop the previous alarm. but i don't want that, I'm assigning alarms with different trigger times. **As for my main question**, how do i stop/cancel automatically say, for a certain period of time i.e 5 min, or if it already repeated 3 times then it will automatically stops the alarm.

Comment: already answered for those who are looking for simultaneously alarm firing with different trigger times and for stopping the correct alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody quite got my point, I did a few quick tweaks and found out that my logic was quite off, Sorry.  What i did was implement a snooze and dismiss function, and as for firing alarms with different trigger time simultaneously, i just had to formulate a different `requestCode` for `setRepeating()` and same goes for `set()` <-- if intend to use this method, the requestCode will be used to cancel the correct alarm fired as together with the same signature of the intents you used to fire the alarm..

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea, This is suppose to be done by using a thread in my opinion.  I do however have a quick work around based on my experiences(until somebody gives a better answer). maybe you can work off it.

I have a Chronometer(there is a method that hides it if you dont want the user to see it)

```
    Chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);  //Defines chronometer in layout
            Chrono.start();                                  //Starts Chronometer
            while (!(Chrono.equals(chronoText))) {           /*starts a timer, until it reaches the desired time */
                chronoText = Chrono.getText().toString();    //gets chronometer time and displays it as a string
                if (chronoText.equals("05:00")) {  /*compares if the string is the same as your set time( i put in 5min as an example)*/
                     counter++;  //I explain the counter a outside the block   
                                 //right here is where you will call your method that stops alarm.
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
```

For repeating alarm I would create a loop, then you can just check out that counter i threw in there to see how many times process was repeated.

Comment: what is first value of chronoText before the while loop?.. and for the repeating alarm i don't get the idea of you using loops

Comment: hey im glad to see you figured it out, sorry i haven't been able to get back to your comment fast enough.  I read your solution on the bottom and your method sounds much more efficient, Good Job.